# ¿Cómo incluir el usuario dentro de un archivo log al momento de ejecutar el programa en C#

Tags: c#, archivo

estoy intentado encontrar la manera de poder hacer visible mi usuario dentro de un archivo log que ya puedo generar cada vez que ejecuto mi programa. Habiendo creado una clase aparte llamada LogInformation, en el main principal solamente hago esta ejecución:

LogInformation oLogS = new LogInformation(@"Ruta en dónde guardaré mi archivo");
oLogS.Add("Texto que será visible al txt al momento de ejecutar mi programa");

Mi objetivo es por ejemplo "El usuario(lo que necesito) hizo dicha acción" dentro del txt al momento de ejecutar el programa.

Pero como dije anteriormente, me gustaría encontrar una manera en la que pueda incluir mi usuario de pc para poder este ser visible en mi txt. He intentado dentro de mi variable oLogs ponerle dentro un console.writeline con el método Enviroment.Username pero no es posible, de antemano muchas gracias.

Sino es de más me gustaría saber alguna manera en dónde este archivo además de crearse, pudiera abrirse automáticamente también.

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con Environment.UserName?

Comment: Ya pude resolver con el método String.Format. En un principio no me reconocia el usuario, ahora no.